# Check grammar ambiguity

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, grammar

The following is the extract of a piece of grammar that I'm trying to see whether it is ambiguous or not.

```
Y->b
Y->Z
Z->bW
W->d
W->ϵ
```

When I compute the first set of the grammar I stumble upon this irregularity for first of Y.

```
First(Y) = {b,First(Z)}
First of Z = b so I have the set First(Y)={b,b}.
```

What I want to know is that sufficient enough to prove that the grammar given this evidence is ambigious or not. Or should the set be `First(Y) = {b}`.

Comment: I think all you have proven is that it's not LL1

Comment: Grand just means I have to finish it out and construct the parse table. Just curious seeing that sort of set.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To prove a grammar is ambiguous, you simply need to prove that there's at least two different ways to reach a result.

Considering your example, **and considering your edit**, you do have an ambiguous grammar, since you're be able to derive the expression `b` by:

```
Y -> b
Y -> Z
Z -> bW
Y -> d
W -> ϵ
```

First way:

```
Y -> b
```

Second way:

```
Y -> Z
Y -> Z -> bW
Y -> Z -> bW -> bϵ
Y -> Z -> bW -> bϵ -> b
```

This is an ambiguous grammar.

Comment: I should of noted that E was actually epsilon in this example so yes you are right.