# Checking Ambiguious Grammar

Tags: ambiguity

Is the following grammar ambiguous?

```
       S -> AS | ε

       A -> A1 | 0A1 | 01
```

It's seemed to me that they are ambiguious as

```
           A -> A1->0A11->00111
```

Again,

```
          A-> 0A1 ->0A11->00111
```

Am I right?

Comment: Yes you are correct; see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14091609/check-grammar-ambiguity

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you're right. It's ambiguous as there is more than one leftmost derivation for a given string.

Comment: How can I remove ambiguity from the grammar?